# Getting a list of all files inside a zip/rar/7z file with Scala

Tags: scala, zip, 7zip, rar

Is there a way to get a list of all the files inside a compressed file without decompressing it?

I don't mind using a Java library but all the solutions I found performed a decompression.

Also, if it is relevant, I know that the compressed file has sub directories in it and I want to also get the files from them.

Comment: Looks to me like you can use a  ZipInputStream and getNextEntry, just don't read//decompress the data. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/compress-1565076.html As far as I can tell from a quick read. ZIP itself doesn't support subdirectories, it looks like clients have to parse the filename. But this is from a couple of minutes googling

Comment: thanks I'll try it

Comment: Did you find a solution to this @boaz?

Comment: @NathanielFord - nothing that worked as I wanted, but I didn't had to much time to work in it...will try again in a week or two